# Pintar datos en pantalla AJAX

Tags: ajax

Necesito pintar los datos de un arreglo que tengo en la consola en pantalla
lo intente de esta manera pero no me funciona, necesito extraer solo el texto.
mi código:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>twitter</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="200;">
    <style>
        *{margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}
    
    #myVideo {
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%
    }
    #content-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color :blue;
    margin:0px 600px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top: 270px;
    left: 10px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source id="source-video" src="SectorMovilidad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text"></div>
    <script>
    function twitter () {
        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3300/twitter/sttmed", 
        success: function(result){
        $(".content-text").text(result[0].text);
  }});
    }

</script>

<div></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es poner el texto del resultado de la petición `AJAX` en la clase con id `content-text` esto debería funcionar:

```
$("#content-text").text(result[0].text);
```

Comment: No me quiere funcionar de esta forma

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código HTML para ver la sección content-text? ¿Qué error te aparece con lo que he añadido?

Comment: Mira, ya esta todo el código, no me sale error en consola solo que no se muestran los datos en el content text

Comment: Cambialo por esto:  $("#content-text").text(result[0].text);    Pensaba que content-text era la clase, no el id. Simplemente hay que cambiar el . por #

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Estas mostrando por consola unos datos y por pantalla otros, lo correcto sería mostrar 
`result[0].text`

Prueba de esta forma:

```
function twitter() {
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3300/twitter/sttmed",
        success: function (result) {
            $(result).each(function(key, value){                    
                $("#content-text").append('<p>'+value.text+'</p>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Con [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) iterarás por cada elemento del array (por si te llega más de un elemento)

**Edito**

He añadido el selector correcto `$("#content-text")` faltaba la almahadilla, en caso de que se seleccione por `id`.

Comment: Mira ya tengo solo el texto, como puedo pintarlo en pantalla quemado?

Comment: ¿quemado? que quieres decir?

Comment: Pues el texto Así como esta en consola

Comment: $(".content-text").text(result[0].text); y de esta forma no me funciona

Comment: Por favor, no elimines contenido de la pregunta, añade las aclaraciones que haga falta pero no borres información. Además, deberías mostrarnos el código, no pantallazos, así no puedo ayudarte pues no se de donde sale ese texto.